# How to set common request headers for every ajax request in ext5?

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs5

I have to set customized headers for every ajax request, is there a way to do this only once without having to config it manually in every ajax proxy.

```
proxy: {
   headers: {
      token: 'xyz' // this token that every proxy should contain to communicate with our remote server. 
   }
}
```

In jQuery i can accomplish this by using "ajaxPrefilter" like following:

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('token', 'xyz');
}
```

But i don't known how to do it properly in extjs, please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({
            'Accept':'application/json'
        });
```

Comment: Can I write this in Ext.application's launch function() ??

Answer (score 0):

how about overriding Ext.data.proxy.Ajax like this

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.proxy.Ajax, {
    headers: {
        token: 'xyz' // this token that every proxy should contain to communicate with your remote server. 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Ajax is a singleton, so you should be able to do this:

```
Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
  token: 'xyz'
};
```

Place it at the beginning of your app, or where you see fit, and then each subsequent Ajax request will have this token.

Comment: `Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
      token: 'xyz'
    };` doesn't work for me, instead `Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({ token: 'xyz' })` works fine, but i don't know the difference between **defaultHeaders** and **setDefaultHeaders**.

Comment: What's stranger is that I can't find `setDefaultHeaders` anywhere in the 4.2.1 docs.  I imagine it's just a wrapper for setting the `defaultHeaders` variable... and [according to the 5.0.1 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-method-setDefaultHeaders), that's exactly what it does.

Comment: currently i'm using extjs5, it has `#setDefaultHeaders` method, please refer to [http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Ajax].

Answer (score 0):

Below code adds CSRF header and token to every ajax request made. Note beforerequest

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(conn, options) {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
    var token = "";
    var headerVal = ""; 
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].name == "_csrf")
        {
             token = x[i].content;
        }else if (x[i].name=="_csrf_header"){
             headerVal = x[i].content;
        }
    }

    //Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = Ext.apply(Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders || {}, { headerVal : token });
    Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({
        headerVal : token
    });
});
```